# Wie würdet ihr »Gender« ins Deutsche übersetzen?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich weiß, ich weiß. *Gender* ist jetzt [Teil des deutschen Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gender). Allerdings halte ich dies trotz allem für ziemlich langweilig und ein Zeichen für Faulheit.

Wenn ihr ein deutsches Wort für *Gender* erfinden dürftet (oder eine alternative Formulierung für das Wort finden könntet), wie würde es dann aussehen?

Comment: Ist denn schon Wortfindungsweihnachten?

Comment: Finde auch, dass eine Frage nach dem Motto "Wenn ihr [...] erfinden dürftet,..." nicht mit der SE-Philosophie zusammenpasst.

Comment: Was ist falsch an [Genus, Gattung, Geschlecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus)? Ok ersteres ist auch ein Fremdwort, aber die anderen nicht.

Comment: @Takkat: *Geschlechtsaktivist* funktioniert zwar, wird aber mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit anders aufgefasst als *Genderaktivist* ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich mag das vom Duden vorgeschlagene *Geschlechtsidentität* (siehe Bedeutungsübersicht im von dir verlinktem Wörterbucheintrag). Ich empfinde es als passend, da es sperrig und konstruiert klingt. Auch glaube ich, kann es als eines dieser sehr fachlich-bürokartischen Wörter, die kein normaler Deutschsprecher in einer Alltagssituation verwenden würde, empfunden werden.

Irgendwie witzig, dass der Duden das Wort [Geschlechtsidentität](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Geschlechtsidentit%C3%A4t) erfinden muss, um den Eintrag Gender zu erklären. Vielleicht das einzige Wort im Duden, das es nötig hat, mit einem extra dafür erfundenen Wort erklärt zu werden.

Comment: Ich möchte annehmen, dass nicht die Dudenredaktion des Wort *Geschlechtsidentität* eingeführt hat. Vielmehr wird es schon irgendwo - und sei es in entsprechenden soziologischen Fachpublikationen - verwendet gewesen sein, und die Dudenredaktion zog es dann sinnvollerweise ebenfalls heran, um "Gender" zu erklären.

Comment: Wieso so polemisch? Das englische Wort "gender" ist ja nicht so "fachlich-bürokratisch", dass es "kein normaler" Englischsprecher verwenden würde. Wiese soll die deutsche Entsprechung dann so sperrig wie möglich sein?

Answer (score 7):

Soziales Geschlecht. Das englische `Sex` wäre dann das biologische Geschlecht.

Oder du bezeichnest das biologische Geschlecht als *Sexus* und alles andere als subjektive Schubladen.